# How can I generate thread dump for jnlp application in java

Tags: java, jnlp, thread-dump

I am trying to debug a jnlp application.
It get hanged after some scenario.

I want to collect thread dump of my jnlp application.

Any suggestion regarding how to do that.

I am running it in Win XP, 32 bit jvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNLP application runs exactly like any java application. JNLP role ends when application has downloaded to client machine.

Now reproduce your scenario and use jstack or jps commands that you can find in your jdk.